# Why does time data not match format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with strings that I am converting to datetimes. They all look like "12/20/17 5:45:30" (month/day/year hour:minute:second). This is my code:

```
for col in cols:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: time data '4/19/16 1:05:30' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

The date shown in the error is the very first date in the dataframe, so it is not working at all. Can someone explain what's wrong with my `datetime` format? How does that `datetime` not match the format? By the way, before I was doing this with a file that had no seconds, and my format was `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M`, which worked fine, but now with seconds it does not.

Comment: Take a look at this table: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: The point of @JacobIRR's comment seems to be: Read carefully what `%Y` really means. Note that this is not the same thing as `%y`.

Comment: I see the problem now, two of my columns contain seconds while the rest do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format string is not working because your format uses a `Y` where it needed a `y`.  But pandas to the rescue, it can often figure this stuff out for you by using the `infer_datetime_format` parameter to `pandas.to_datetime()`

**Code:**

```
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["12/20/17 5:45:30", "4/19/16 1:05:30"], columns=['date'])

print(df)    
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], infer_datetime_format=True)
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
               date
0  12/20/17 5:45:30
1   4/19/16 1:05:30

                 date
0 2017-12-20 05:45:30
1 2016-04-19 01:05:30
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but do you know why specifying the format doesn't work? Also, doesn't inferring the format make it a little slower?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to do with leading zeros. Python's date formatting can cope with missing leading zeros. It has to do with OP not giving the right format. Which is exactly what the error message is saying.